# SQL Query to get Count within a Stored Proc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

So i need to figure out how i can get a record count value and use that count as a new value to insert into a table.

> Ex:  In My Stored Procedure

@Count int

***What im looking for***

@Count to equal "select top (1) _fieldName from _someTable order by _fieldName Desc"

***Finally***

insert into _newTable (_fieldName) values (@Count)

> End

I dont have to use a variable, just trying to demonstrate what im really trying to do.  My SQL knowledge is pretty limited so no laughing, or smirking! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, then why not use the [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In  SQL SERVER

```
       DECLARE @Count INT
        SET @COUNT = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable
        insert into newTable (fieldName) values (@Count)

     OR


      INSERT INTO newTable (fieldName)
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `INSERT-SELECT`.  That is an `INSERT` that uses all the rows returned from the `SELECT` as the values to insert.  So try something like this (SQL Server example code):

```
DECLARE @TableToCount  table (fieldName varchar(5))
INSERT INTO @TableToCount VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @TableToCount VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @TableToCount VALUES ('C')

DECLARE @TableToStore  table (fieldName int)

INSERT INTO @TableToStore
    (fieldName)
    SELECT 
        COUNT(fieldName)
        FROM @TableToCount

SELECT * FROM @TableToStore
```

OUTPUT:

```
fieldName
-----------
3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database, so I'll write Sybasish.

```
declare @count int
select @int = count (1) from  ... the rest of your query
insert another_table values (@count, 'other_field')
```

Answer (score 0):

What i was looking for was the identity of the insert during the stored proc.  complete this a while back but wanted to post the final answer.

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()